# Blank screen when I convert the localhost site into an app

Tags: java, android

I have a site built in HTML (front-end) and Node.js (back-end), I have to create an app with Android Studio that displays the site.
To do this I wrote the following code:

```
package com.example.apayron2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:<5000>");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }

    public class myWebClient extends  WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,  String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And set these settings in the emulator
manual proxy configuration: host name 10.0.2.2, port 5000

The emulator used is Nexus 5X API 29

The problem is that when I run it, it gives me an empty screen
please explain step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem I posted.
The problem was that I had written the port <5000>, instead it had to be written 5000 without <>